# MathGL doesn t compile under Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, mathgl

I have tried to install this morning MathGL trough my terminal: brew install mathGL and it worked pretty well.  After that I added the framework and includes-lib path to my c++ project under Xcode. The problem comes when I compile it that I get  this Linker warnings:

Semantic Isssue 'mgl_ipowc' has C-linkage speceified, but returns user-defined type ''dual"...

I get 16 issues from the same file: datac_cf.h Someone knows what I am doing bad?I would appreciate some clue. I googled it a lot but there is nothing out there apparently.

Many thanks

Comment: Why not ask the MathGL developers? Don't they have a mailing list?

Comment: I did that as well, was my first option. No answers so far, so I decided to post the post here as well